# Including a date/time in a file name dumped from psql

Tags: linux, postgresql, sh

I'm planning on running a .sh script that will run periodically through cron on linux.  I'm running postgres 8.4 on centos.

My script will have something like this in it:

```
psql -U username -d db_name -c "COPY orders TO stdout DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;" > orders.csv
```

I know there are other ways to dump tables into csv files but this is the only one I could use without admin rights.

My problem is naming the files.  I want to specifically name the file something along the lines of:
yyyymmdd-hhmm-orders.csv

I'm not the best scripting guru out there (as you can tell) so how can I get the dumps to dynamically do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M'`-orders.csv
```

I personally also add the seconds %S to the file name

```
man date
```

Will show the other formatting options

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and its worked fine

Assigned date format with one variable and used the same

Code:

```
I=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S -d`
psql -U username -d db_name -c "COPY orders TO stdout DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;" > $i-orders.csv
```